# Reverse proxy with login for redirecting different users to different applications

Tags: networking, proxy, reverse-proxy, redirect, http-server

Im trying to configure the topology you can see in this picture:

[image: this picture]

My question is, having a unique login server acting as a reverse proxy, is it posible to redirect the users to their respective server application? 
This way they will be using the same login link, but each user will be redirected to their particular application

Comment: I can't currently dig very deep into this, but haproxys [stick-table](https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/configuration-1.5.html#4-stick-table) [looks promising](https://www.haproxy.com/blog/introduction-to-haproxy-stick-tables/).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have been checking stick-tables and it looks more like for load balancing, i dont think i could be able to manage sesssions through servers with it.

Comment: @adrecleto How does `app-server-a` verify that the user has correctly authenticated? When you say "redirected", do you actually mean HTTP 302 - or maybe you mean "proxied"?

Comment: Authentification is what im trying to know how to do, im looking into using JWT + blacklisting closed sessions from the app server when logged out